# Good practice to achieve this eventual consistency

Tags: api, rest, events, domain-driven-design, akka

In my application, when a user is created, an Event called `UserCreatedEvent` is thrown.

*This user must have all his description data retrieved from Facebook (with his authorization of course) and should be treated by some custom process.*

I chose to apply eventual consistency (using Akka and his eventStream feature to handle events) between the fact of saving the user aggregate and the fact to retrieve all his description data and apply them, since it involves some call network to Facebook.

The point is I also allowed any newly created user to override some of the description (job, age etc.) through the REST api `PUT /api/users/:id`.

1) Should the process of handling `UserCreatedEvent` (basically an Akka actor) call this api (causing an indirection) to assign default user description (from Facebook) or should it retrieve and update user itself?

2) Should the process of handling `UserCreatedEvent` and the api aiming to manage User (CRUD) be part of the same bounded context? (in that case, no recommendation to involve the indirection).

Comment: What does are the that user can override? Facebook's info?

Comment: I store custom user descriptions in my DB. I just init their contents with their Facebook data; that user can then override ( letting Facebook untouched) if they want to.

Comment: @Mik378 Is there an invariant in your domain that requires the presence of "description data" for a user ? If so, what compensating action do you intend to take if the Facebook stuff fails ? What does eventual consistency bring you here, vs. fetching the Facebook data beforehand ?

Comment: There's no invariant. I have a complex mechanism to build a graph of friends of friends of friends .. so it takes some "time", that's why I opted for eventual consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I would call this eventual consistency, since consistency (making sure that an entity respects invariants) is not at stake. This is more like out-of-band asynchronous data completion.

What hoops this side process has to go through again basically depends on your context :

- REST API if there's important stuff there you want to reapply (logging, security, whatever)
- Application Service / Command handler layer if you want that data completion to be treated as a full blown modification with proper validation (e.g. did Facebook return data that would be unsupported in your application ?)
- In the domain layer, you could model it either as just any other modification of the `User`, or as a specific, maybe more intention-revealing operation : `User.completeDescriptionData(...)`

I wouldn't necessarily place this in a different Bounded Context since it doesn't introduce a new definition of User. It's important that the part that knows the nitty gritty details of talking to Facebook is in a separate non domain layer though.

Comment: I'm about to model it as a command handler. It makes better sense for this case. Thanks for your answer ;)